# C# Why am I getting an out of memory exception when uploading large files?

Tags: c#

I'm reading a large file into a stream, of which I'm filling a 4k buffer which I'm writing to a HttpWebRequest stream.

For some reason I'm getting out of memory exceptions, not sure why.

Am I doing something incorrectly?

My method:

```
public void StreamBlob(FileInfo file, Uri blobContainerSasUri, string containerName)
{
    try
    {
        var method = "PUT";
        var token = blobContainerSasUri.Query;
        var requestUri =
            new Uri($"https://{blobContainerSasUri.Host}/{containerName}/{string.Concat(file.Name, token)}");

        using (var fileStream = file.OpenRead())
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
            request.Method = method;
            request.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(file.FullName);
            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");
            request.ContentLength = fileStream.Length;
            request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;

            using (var serverStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                var buffer = new byte[4096];
                while (true)
                {
                    var bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (bytesRead > 0)
                        serverStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    else
                        break;
                }
            }

            using (var resp = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        _logger.Log.Info("Received http response {resp}");
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.Log.Warn($"Received http response {resp}", ex)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Log.Warn($"Error uploading {file.Fullname}, ex")
    }
```

Comment: Are you monitoring your resource consumption when running this?

Comment: where are you getting the exceptions?  remove the `try-catch` statements for the time being, and you will be able to find where you run out of memory.

Comment: How big is the file you're reading into memory? Sounds like you might want to ensure your buffer is the right length with var buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length]; Also, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809514/outofmemoryexception-when-i-read-500mb-filestream

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send and receive large file over streams in ASP.NET Web Api C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43678963/send-and-receive-large-file-over-streams-in-asp-net-web-api-c-sharp)

Comment: @sr28 You absolutely don't want your buffer to be the size of the file. Than you will hold the complete file in memory.

Comment: You can simplify the transfer of the data to: `fileStream.CopyTo(serverStream)`

Comment: How about if you set `AllowWriteStreamBuffering` to `true` and don't set `ContentLength` at all?

Comment: @Magnus almost immediate out of memory exception

Comment: Where is the exception coming from in the stack trace?

Comment: Interestingly after changing it to fileStream.CopyTo I now get 
"  Message=The stream does not support concurrent IO read or write operations."

Comment: How about setting AllowWriteStreamBuffering to true before GetResponse() ?

Comment: Operation timed out emanating from System.HttpWebRequest