# need for an in process "pipe" on a stream

Tags: c#, .net-core, stream

I have the following code:

```
public  override async Task<Empty> MirrorFull(IAsyncStreamReader<StringPayload> requestStream, ServerCallContext context)
        {

            MyQueueHandler fqh = new MyQueueHandler(...);
            while(await requestStream.MoveNext(CancellationToken.None))
            {
                logger.Debug($"**RECEIVE MIRROR MESSAGE FOR FULL**");
                //I've read a string from source stream reader, i need to push on the fqh stream...
            }
            return new Empty();
        }
```

so I'm in a gRPC server that receive a stream of strings from a gRPC. The queue handler has a function:

```
public override async Task  ConsumeAsync(Stream stream)
```

I want to "pipe" the received string continuosly in the ConsumeAsync, so I need some sort of PipeStream, but I did not find it ( apparently the PipeStream class is not what I need ) how can I do it?

Comment: Reading this code, it looks like you are actually consuming the stream inside `MirrorFull` already. Perhaps your queuehandler should actually be a `Queue<string>`? So you enqueue strings inside `MirrorFull` and dequeue from some other Task.

Comment: @JessedeWit something more complex, inside the ConsumeAsync I'm consuming the stream with a JSonTextReader.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'pipe the received string continuously'. The streamreader will return a stringpayload (=string?) in each iteration of the while loop.  What is this Stream you want to consume exactly?

Comment: Review the following two links, they deal with the similar use case:

[Large Json Array Streaming](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1180464/Large-JSON-Array-Streaming-in-ASP-NET-Web-API) ,

[Large Files Over WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43678963/send-and-receive-large-file-over-streams-in-asp-net-web-api-c-sharp),

You surely need to make changes, but idea is to stream from server and enabled chunking at the protocol level and receive the stream at the client