# Upload more than 4 GB file into .net Core 5 API

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5, rest

What i have  tried :

```
<system.webServer>
< security >
  < requestFiltering >
    < requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" / >
  </ requestFiltering >
</ security>
```

</system.webServer>

and

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(o =>
        {o.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            o.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 4294967295;
            o.MemoryBufferThreshold = int.MaxValue;
        });
        services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options => {
            options.MaxRequestBodySize = 4294967295;
        });
```

but its limited to 4 gb.. but my client wan to transfer file of 16 gb through this Rest API. i doubt that. is it possible ?

Comment: Passing 16 gig over a rest api makes it seem like the solution should be rethought. The larger the file the more problematic this becomes. Have you thought about other cloud solutions?

Comment: Does [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43678963/send-and-receive-large-file-over-streams-in-asp-net-web-api-c-sharp) answer your question? - simply use streaming for transferring the file.